# I can only add comments to a question if a previous comment is present

Tags: support, comments

I can add comments to a question, if any previous comment is already present. Also, I can add a comment to an answer.

I cannot find any button to add a comment to a question when I'm the first one to comment. Is this a question of permissions, did I just miss it, or is it a bug?

I'm using Firefox 5 and see the same behaviour at Stack Overflow and Exchange, as well as in the previous Firefox version (updated just a few minutes ago).

**Update:** Right now I can see the "add comment" link in some cases, but on Stack Overflow now I can't even add comments to questions that have been commented on before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need more than 50 reputation (except here on meta) to be able to comment on other people's posts.

You can always comment on your own posts (questions and answers) and comment on answers to your own questions.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks! That's quite not intuitive, so I'ld recommend to add a message instead of this button at that place.

Unfortunately I have to file an answer instead of a comment even if I just have a question just to better understand the original question.

Comment: What a nice coincidence :-) Right now I gained some other reputation points on SO and now passed the magic wall of 50 points. You all are right, the "add comment" button now seems to be present in every question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You need [50 reputation to comment](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) on every post.

With less that 50 reputation you can only comment on your own posts.

So that's probably what has happened.

Answer (score 2):

It might relate more to *which posts* you are trying to comment on; is this within the context of your *own* questions? or on other people's? You need a nominal rep (50, IIRC) to comment on questions that aren't yours.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Firefox on my computer, and I cannot reproduce this issue.

If you don't have any UserScript that removes the link to add a comment from the question pages, then (basing on your reputation on Stack Overflow), you should be able to comment everywhere on your questions, and in your answers.
As reported in the ["comment everywhere" privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment):

> Please note that you can *always* comment on your own posts, and any part of your questions. However, commenting on other people's posts is a privilege.

The "comment everywhere" privilege is a privilege you get when your reputation reaches 50; your reputation on Stack Overflow is 16.

Comment: You're right, it was 16 when I asked this question. Now it's 51 and the problem is gone. Thanks again for all your quick help!